# Chain has_many :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to chain has_many through relationships. In my example I have a user whom can have multiple roles. Each role has multiple permissions. So a user has multiple permissions. The code below works fine, but I am wonder if there is a better way to do this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_user_mappings
  has_many :roles, through: :role_user_mappings

  def permissions
    permitted_actions = []
    self.roles.each do |role|
       role.permissions.each do |permission|
         permitted_actions << permission
       end
    end
    permitted_actions
  end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permission_role_mappings
  has_many :permissions, through: :permission_role_mappings
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class PermissionRoleMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :permission
  belongs_to :role
end

class RoleUserMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

I would like to be able to do this.

```
user.permissions
```

**EDIT: Tried**
On thing that I tried that at least DRYs the User model a little bit is adding the function as a concern

```
module Permittable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def permissions
    permitted_actions = []
    self.roles.each do |role|
       role.permissions.each do |permission|
         permitted_actions << permission
       end
    end
    permitted_actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_user_mappings
  has_many :roles, through: :role_user_mappings
  has_many :permissions, through: roles
```

That should give you

```
user.permissions
```

I'm not sure when the HMT via HMT  feature was made available, I know it was missing in earlier versions of rails,  but it works for me on Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permission_role_mappings
end
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_user_mappings
  has_many :roles, through: :role_user_mappings

  def permissions
    Permission.
      joins(:permission_role_mappings).
      where(permission_role_mappings: {role: roles})
  end
end
```

By the way, you may already know this and it may be why you're asking the question... but this is going to give you an N+1 query:

```
  permitted_actions = []
  self.roles.each do |role|
     role.permissions.each do |permission|
       permitted_actions << permission
     end
  end
  permitted_actions
```

Also, FWIW, when wanting an `array` back from a collection, you don't need to do:

```
  permitted_actions = []
  self.roles.each do |role|
     ...
  end
  permitted_actions
```

You can just do:

```
  roles.map do |role|
    ...
  end
```

Since `map` returns an `array`.